# Call function on string literal

Tags: php

I am wondering whether it is possible to call functions on string literals (Like in Python) in PHP (Tried googling, but 90% sure my terminology is off).

Example python:

```
"test,1,2,3".split()
```

I want to achieve something like (In php psuedo code):

```
$result = "SELECT `db`.`table`.`field` FROM `db`.`table` WHERE 1"->query();
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
$result = MySql::query("SELECT `db`.`table`.`field` FROM `db`.`table` WHERE 1");
```

But I really like the simplicity of the middle example and was wondering if anything like that is possible in PHP, maybe by overriding the PHP string class?

Comment: AFAIK there no way to do it in PHP since strings are not classes.

Comment: No. Strings in PHP are just bytes. In order to call a method on something it needs to be an object. If you want syntactic sugar like that then you should be using a language that supports it.

Comment: It might in the far-fetched future; https://github.com/nikic/scalar_objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that everything in Python (and similar OO languages) is an object, that's why even strings have "methods" and "properties". PHP isn't a full top-to-bottom OO language, strings are just primitive strings. Even if they were objects, a string probably wouldn't have methods pertaining to database queries, because that'd be quite weird OO design with terribly mixed responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to do what you're talking about

```
$result = "SELECT `db`.`table`.`field` FROM `db`.`table` WHERE 1"->query();
```

In this example, your string is just a string. You then try to reference it like an object. In this case, you would get a `Fatal` error because you're telling PHP to use an object where none exists.

The closest thing to what you describe is direct chaining, where you create an instance of the class and reference it in the same statement (available in [PHP >= 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php))

```
$class = (new Class())->function();
```